# When to test what with Cucumber and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, cucumber, functional-testing

As I am writing tests in Cucumber and Ruby on Rails, I keep asking myself this question. When do I test "how do I create X" vs "can X be created"

How do I create X seems to encompass testing the actual steps it takes for a user to create X, commonly through a form. 
Such as navigate to the new page, click the "create X" link, fill out the form and click create and then see that X has been created.

The alternative, "can x be created", is whether the system, model and controller, handle the capacity to create X, aka are they wired up properly.

Do I usually test both of these scenarios? I just barely started writing a Question and Answer part to my side project, and couldn't decide whether to write the test something like (I have removed the backgrounds, they are kind of long)

```
When I click "Ask the seller a question"
And I fill out the form with a question and submit the form
Then I should see that the question has been created
And the user that posted the job has been notified
```

or should it be  more like

```
When I ask the seller a question
Then I should see that the question has been posted
And the user that posted the job has been notified
```

The difference being whether I create it through a form or factory, correct? Where does Rspec come into play, I think it should be testing the "can X be created" and does that mean I shouldn't be using cucumber to test that?

I think i'm essentially looking at "What do I test with cucumber", but maybe i'm making this more complicated then it is but I am having trouble coming to the conclusion by myself. Any insight you have would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you described as "how do I create X" is better because you're taking user perspective for testing, which is imho more natural/popular for Cucumber.

Also, this approach is better from the documentation perspective -> you describe how something works and not "what's expected". So if you need an refreshment or there is a new developer on a project -> you or him can just read a scenario.

You can read a bit about user perspective testing here: http://www.businesstechnologyarticles.eu/testing-the-user-perspective-with-ruby-on-rails

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I would answer differently. The Cucumber scenarios should be more like 'can X be created' (I mean your second example) but use only Capybara in steps with very little of Ruby code, RSpec, FactoryGirl... 
Since web_steps were removed from Cucumber you should not be tempted to write such steps:

```
When I click "Ask the seller a question"
And I fill out the form with a question and submit the form
```

This is a really bad approach.

The second example is much better

```
When I ask the seller a question
Then I should see that the question has been posted
And the user that posted the job has been notified
```

It is more about the general idea without going to details

but you should write mostly Capybara steps then which will have all the details about 'how do I create X'.

Example:

```
When(/^I ask the seller a question$/) do
  click_link 'Ask the seller a question'
  fill_in 'my_form', with: 'My question'
  click_button 'Submit'
end

Then(/^I should see that the question has been posted$/) do
  expect(page).to have_selector '.alert', text: 'New question has been posted.'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Question: My question'
end
```